# Split epimorphisms and regular ones.

Tags: category-theory

It is well known that any split epimorphism is in particular a regular one, but the converse is not true in arbitrary categories. Is there any meaningful context where we have that the converse is always true ? At first, I thought about regular or abelian categories but it is not the case.

Comment: There is terminology for this: "Every object is regular projective" or "the external regular axiom of choice holds." But I don't know anything about cases in which this occurs other than if every object is *projective*, that is, every epi splits or the external axiom of choice holds.

Answer (score 1):

Some of those categories are called semisimple, which is quite a strong property! Which additionally demands every object to be a sum of its simples. For example finite dimensional vector spaces and finite sets have that property.

Also algebraic objects are usually called semisimple if the category of finitely generated modules over them is semisimple.

Comment: Any litterature on semisimple categories ?

Comment: anything on category theory should do. However, one usually does not want to use them, since it is really quite restrictive, for example the derived categories for those are already the homotopy categories...

also, this is equivalent to all short exact sequences splitting, and that is quite the assumption!

Comment: I have heard the phrase "semisimple category" many times to refer to an *abelian* category in which every object is a sum of *finitely many* simple objects. This certainly does not apply to either category you listed. In both categories you listed, it's also true that every epimorphism is regular, so it would be valuable to give a citation for this terminology, if it's really ever used in this way, and some examples that more clearly answer the question that was asked.

Comment: sorry you are completely right. Forgot the finitely generated part of a semisimple category. But to my knowledge that is the most commonly used case for categories with this property. since you usually do not just want the split, but also some control over the objects.

Comment: @Enkidu Well, it depends on what you mean by "use." Semisimple (abelian) categories are objects you can think of as basically generalized vector spaces, very concrete and amenable to computation. But clearly the category of sets is "used" rather often!